# Swift 4 in Xcode 9 - How to use boundingrect in NSAttributedstring?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsattributedstring

I want to get the length of some texts in UILabel, and change the width property of UILabel dynamically.

But I have no idea about how to set the parameters in the function boundingrect.
This is the documentation of Apple Developer.

```
func boundingRect(with size: CGSize, 
      options: NSStringDrawingOptions = [], 
      context: NSStringDrawingContext?) -> CGRect
```

,and I tried like this

```
let attr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "test test test test , this is test text. test test test test , this is test text. test test test test , this is test text. ")
//attr.addattributes
print(attr.boundingrect(with: CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: 0), option: .truncatesLastVisibleLine
,context: nil)!)
```

But finally I got false width in print,so why and how to get the correct one.

Comment: It returns `(0.0, -2.759765625, 540.193359375, 13.8)` in my playground. How is that false? What result do you expect?

Comment: @CodeDifferent you get correct data ? OK, I will try again. Sometimes it returns width in this cgrect is obvious small.(e.g. it return width 100, but now its width is equal with the width of screen)

Comment: @CodeDifferent Oh ! I have solved this problem, the main problem is my attributed string hasn't same attributes.Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
public extension NSAttributedString {
    public func width(height: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                            options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                            context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
}
```

and then get let width = attr.width(height: height)
where **height > 0**

Comment: Oh ! I have solved this problem, the main problem is my attributed string hasn't same attributes.Thanks!

Comment: "return ceil(boundingBox.height)" need to be "return ceil(boundingBox.width)", no ?